# Importing a top-level member of a library in Dart

Tags: dart

What is the Dart equivalent of the following Python syntax for importing just a part of a module?  This imports just `urlopen` from the `urllib2` module.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

Answer (score 5):

To import only a part of a library, you can do the following. This imports only `foo` and `bar`:

```dart
import 'package:lib1/lib1.dart' show foo, bar;
```

And this imports everything *except* `foo`:

```dart
import 'package:lib2/lib2.dart' hide foo;
```